# Mouse is disconnecting randomly but keyboard is not

Tags: usb, temperature

Мy mouse only works when my room temperature is less than 25 degrees Celsius!

When it gets a bit warmer, it stops working and keeps disconnecting until it's finally disconnected.

But my keyboard, flash drives, and other things are always fine. For example, when my mouse isn't working, I quickly remove the mouse and plug in a keyboard instead and the keyboard turns on and works just fine.

I'm almost sure that my mouse is fine. I've tried my friend's mouse and the same thing happens.

I have unchecked the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" of my USB Root Hubs and I have no "USB INPUT DEVICE" in my device manager.

My CPU and GPU temps are always less than 55°C.

What's wrong?

Comment: What kind of mouse? Ordinary cabled LS mouse, or FS wireless? What is your host system? Which ICH or other USB host controller does it have? Is it a USB 3.0 port? What Device Manager says when the mouse gets frozen? What USBTreeView shows?

Comment: It's a cabled mouse and it's written:3D optical mouse, 5v...100mA, FFC standards behind it. it's a cheap mouse but I really like its design, it's convenient and I don't think it's USB 3.0 and its port is not blue. I have a Wireless mouse and It's working fine but I don't like to work with a wireless mouse while using PC and their design are not good for gaming. Here's my Image of device manager and CMD(ipconfig /all): "https://imgur.com/a/ihjCsnR " I just hear a sound while disconnecting and Device manager shows nothing special! even the message "USB NOT RECOGNIZING" is not showing.